# AD/2003 Computer Group membership is not propagated to client

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a Windows network based on an ageing Windows Server 2003 infrastructure, with two DCs, configured with replication between each other.

While trying to find out why a certain GPO wasn't being applied, I discovered that the computer group membership isn't being set correctly on the actual computer. Running as administrator: `gpresult /v` only lists the default groups, and not the other groups the computer is a member of. These groups are shown if I go to "Member of" for the computer account in the domain. The groups are global security groups (and not distribution).

If I apply the GPO setting to the Default Domain Policy, it's applied on the computer as well - so it's able to get its GPO settings and apply them.

Any user group membership is available, even if the user has just been added to the group.

I've tried klist purge, both with and without specificity (-lh, etc), removing the computer from the domain (from the computer itself) and rejoining it to the domain. No change (if anything I lost the membership of the group "domain computers").

I've verified that replication between the DCs work with `dcdiag` and `dcdiag /c`, and the `gpresult /v` call shows the main DC (which is also IM) as the source (I've seen both - no change).

I'm completely lost about how to debug this any further; whoami /groups doesn't show anything except for the builtin groups. There are no warnings or errors in the event log for either DC server.

Comment: What is the group type?

Comment: @GregAskew Global, Security, not distribution

Comment: Universal, Global, DomainLocal?

Comment: @GregAskew Global, just edited my comment. DC Mode is set to Windows Server 2003.

Comment: If you run the Group Policy Modeling Wizard against the computer, does it show the GPO in scope to apply?

Comment: @GregAskew It shows in the wizard as "The selected computer is a member of the following security groups ..."

Comment: Actually the 2003 GPMC may not have the modeling wizard.  If you run GPMC from a modern operating system, does the modeling wizard show the policy applying and settings?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771389.aspx

Comment: The GPMC in W2K3 does have the Group Policy Modeling wizard as well as the Group Policy Results wizard, if you have the GPMC installed.

Comment: Yes, W2K3 does have them available (which was my update just under). I'll do further testing tomorrow and update the question accordingly.